# Check if an xml file is still being transfered c#

Tags: c#, xml

i have an application which works on a scheduler which converts xml files to csv.
If there is an error while processing the xml file ,the xml file is transfered to another invalid folder.
The issues is that sometimes there are large xml files which are being transfered to be converted and before the transfered is complete
my scheduler application reject the file since its sees the file as an invalid file and transfer it to the invalid folder.
The fact is that the xml file was not ready to be converted to csv but my application once see the xml file, it tries to convert it to csv and reject it.
Is there a way to check if the xml file is ready ? or still being transfered ?

This is the solution what i tried : (Testing in progress)

```
long fileSize = 0;
currentFile = new FileInfo(path);

while (fileSize < currentFile.Length)//check size is stable or increased
{
fileSize = currentFile.Length;//get current size
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);//wait a moment for processing copy
currentFile.Refresh();//refresh length value
}
```

Then i proceed with the conversion of the xml file

Comment: _"Is there a way to check if the xml file is ready ?"_ -- sure. Read it and if it's valid, it's ready. If it's not valid, it's not ready. Did you try anything? Another option is to not allow read sharing on the file when writing it, so that your application can't open it until the other program is done writing it and has closed it. There are lots of other mechanism you might use as well. Your question is too broad. You should do some research and try _something_.

Comment: @Peter i am currently search how to do it. Actually the xml file is a file which i don't have hands on,The xml file comes in a folder and i need to read it and convert to csv. actually my app don't see it as in use because it tries to convert it once the file appear in the folder. In xml if the tags are not properly ended the file is rejected,thus if i read it instantly it will always give me error an reject the file. I don't know if i can check is the file size is continuously processing ?? any thought?

Comment: How is the file being transferred.  The error is in the transfer function and you should not be trying to kludge your code by checking the xml.  You should have an exception handler in your code so when the error does occur you can report it properly.

Comment: Do what firefox does. Create the file with a temporary extension (e.g. `.temp`, `.part`, etc.) and once it's done - rename it. That only works if you create or transfer the file yourself of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check xml file size some times. If return several same results, you can consider as the file has been transfered completely.

Comment: i have tried this, thanks , i shall update the codes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thread to do the xml transfer operation. So that you can check whether the thread gets completed or not.
After it gets completed you can do your conversion process